# What Application for Vector and Cartesian Coordinate System

Tags: sql-server, geometry, spatial-database, cartogram

**Goal:**
Visualize a picture in SQL server 2012 spatial data based on geometry

**Problem:**
In order to display a vector picture I need to retrieve X, Y coordinate (cartesian coordinate system) and display it in the SQL server spatial data.

I'm looking for a tool that can draw vector graphic. Every object of line, point or zone you make, you shall enable to retrieve X and Y coordination from the start to the end of the object. For instance line object has start point (0,0) and end point (5,3).

The reason why I need this X,Y data is to use them in SQL server to visualize a vector picture.

> What tool do I need to use?

**Other Important Info:**

- Please take account that I do not want to use geography data because the x-and y-coordinate data that are not defined in relation to any
  particular model of the Earth, it's using the geometry datatype with
  SRID = 0
- The X and Y data retrieve from the special application shall be enable to use in SQL server. In other word, same cartesian coordinate system without measurement of unit.
- It's important that this application can apply gif or jpeg picture to act as a background and om top on it, you draw a vector geometry data.
- This application should also take account to [Well-known text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) to be customized with SQL server and its spatial data. In other word, take account to OGC standard
- The picture from a paper map or jpeg will be a subway map that is a linear cartogram [image: linear cartogram]

Answer (score 1):

If you are not afraid to write some code, R is an excellent tool to perform this kind of tasks. A graphics package like `ggplot2` would be suitable for a task like this, it simply draws what you specify and is not particularly meant for geographic data. R can connect to any kind of database you want, e.g. see `RODBC`, so getting the data into R is possible.

R may have a relatively steep learning curve, but once you are up-to-speed you have a very flexible and powerful tool in your arsenal.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use MapInfo Professional.

With MI Pro 11.5 you can connect to SQL Server 2012, open a table with spatial data and display it in a map window. You can also add new vector objects and save these back to the database.

You can download a 30 day evaluation version of MapInfo Professional here: [MI Pro 30 day trial](http://web.pb.com/mipro-11-5-welcome)

I did a presentation on how to use MapInfo Professional with a spatial database (SQL Server 2008) at the MapInfo User Group for UK and Ireland in January last year. You can find my presentation on [slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/peterhorsbollmoller/muguki-session-on-mi-pro-11-and-sql-server-2008-english-pbs)

Comment: This application is very interesting. I will contact you by e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use lates [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) (its OO), it has MSSQL Spatial support, just dont define SRID. Use geometry data type.

Comment: OO? What do you mean? If I understand correctly, you can geometry data type without measurement of unit?

Comment: Usually it uses srid's units when you use st_distance or similiar functions. But i dont understand what measurement of unit has to do with it. from 0 0 to 0 1 is allways 1 long , what that 1 means its up to you.

Comment: Unit of measurement is like pixel, centimeter, inches etc.